# dynamic background color change

Tags: javascript

I'm a javascript noob trying to control and change background colors of my site with javascript based on 3 states. I need a base bg color (my page), then I need to swap for the bg of the following page on img hover, and finally return to base on mouse leave.

So far my set-up is as follow:

-colors are assigned with data-attributes to the pages body and portfolio-items divs in html

-my data-bg is assigned dynamically via a color picker inside my cms (kirby) so I can change colors depending on pages / projects.

Now my problem is this:

I can successfully change my page background color with

`document.body.style.background = document.body.dataset.bg;`

and do my hover state changes with

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
        
    div.addEventListener('mouseenter' , () => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', div.dataset.bg);
    })
    
    div.addEventListener('mouseleave' , () => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', document.body.dataset.bg);
    })
    
    
    })
```

But so far I've been incapable of making the two work together. Any tips on what's wrong ?

Icing on the cake to make this set-up clean, i'd like to move my code inside a .js file instead of a script tag since this principle is almost everywhere on the site. However when inside a .js my code causes my css --background variable to load first before it's replaced by javascript. Tried async and defer with no success.

Many thanks !
v

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help? 
I change a `div` with id box to blue at `mouseEnter`.

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");

box.addEventListener("mouseenter", event => {
  box.style.setProperty("background-color", "blue");
});

box.addEventListener("mouseleave", event => {
  box.style.setProperty("background-color", "white");
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to change the div itself. Need to style the page bg with my stored data-bg first, then change that page bg for another one based on div mouseenter. So to clarify, page load gives data-bg-1, div.mouseenter gives data-bg-xyz, div.mouseleave gives data-bg-1.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do like this :

```
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')
divs.forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener('mouseenter' , () => {
        document.style.backgroundColor = div.dataset.bg;
    })
    
    div.addEventListener('mouseleave' , () => {
        document.style.backgroundColor = document.body.dataset.bg ;
    })
    
    
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem like this, I'm sure there is a nicer way to do this but it works...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', document.body.dataset.bg);
    });

document.querySelectorAll('#color').forEach(div => {
        
    div.addEventListener('mouseenter' , () => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', div.dataset.bg);
    })
    
    div.addEventListener('mouseleave' , () => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', document.body.dataset.bg);
    })
    
    
    })
```